# object is possibly null ts 2531

Tags: typescript

i am trying to return the difference between t1 and t2 given hours in string type.
so i used the regex to match all integers from the string which returned me the array of all integers
then i tried to return the array[0] to access the hour but i got error ts2531 object is possibly null

```
const hoursPassed = (t1:string, t2:string) =>{
        let x  =  t1.match(/\d/g)
        let y =  t2.match(/\d/g)
        return x[0]
    }


        console.log(hoursPassed("3:00 AM", "9:00 AM") )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const hoursPassed = (t1:string, t2:string) =>{
        let x  =  t1.match(/\d/g)
        let y =  t2.match(/\d/g)
        return x?.[0]
}


console.log(hoursPassed("3:00 AM", "9:00 AM") )
```

[Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Depends on what they want for the return type, really.